# Proving disjoint of Kernel & Image of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working on a problem that goes like this:

> Show that $\text{Im} (F)$ and $\text{Ker} (F)$ are disjoint if $F: W \rightarrow W$ is linear and if $F^4 = F.$

Here are what I have come up so far:
(1) For $x \in W$, we have
$$\begin {align}
F^4 (x) &= (F\circ F\circ  F\circ F)(x)\\
&= F(F(F(F(x))))\\
&= F(x),
\end{align}$$
which implies that $F^3$ is an identity mapping.

(2) To prove that $\text{Im} (F)$ and $\text{Ker} (F)$ are disjoint, I need to use contradiction: Assuming that $\exists a \in \text{Ker} (F)$ such that $a \in \text{Im}$ (F), and this assumption eventually ends up with $a = 0.$

But after this my proof does not get any headway. Any help or hint would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Disjoint"? Perhaps you meant "with trivial intersection"? After all, they both contain thezero vector...And  not ncessarily $\;F^4=F\implies F^3=I=$ the identity. This would be so if $\;F\;$ was bijective, say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

$$x\in\ker F\cap\text{Im}\,F\implies Fx=0\;,\;\;x=Fw\implies F^4w=F^3(Fw)=F^3x=0\implies$$

$$x=Fw=F^4w=0\implies x=0$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain the last step in the first line, i.e., I know that $Fx = 0$, but how do you go from that one to $F^3 x =0$? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Since $$Fw=x\implies F^4w=F^3(\overbrace{Fw}^{=x})=F^3x=F^2(Fx)=F^2(0)=0$$

Comment: Thank you, I have green-lighted your response.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $y=Fx$ and $Fy=0$. Then calculate: $(F^4-F)x$.

Comment: Thank you, you response did give me insight.